# Is it possible to change the image src of an image input by clicking on said image?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm just messing around with HTML and Javascript and I was wondering how to make it so where a user clicks on an image and then that image changes after the click. At first I thought it would be a simple function call on a onclick like so:

HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="Images/img.png" id="img" onclick="imgChange()">
```

Javascript:

```
  function imgChange()
{
  var img = document.getElementById("img");

  img.src="Images/img2.png";

}
```

but when executing it it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Is the path to the image right? The code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine.

Check your image location maybe there is a problem.

And try adding a `./` before the address of the image `./` means the current directory

Check this here [Html File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

like this :

```
function imgChange(){
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = "./Images/img2.png";
}
```

And a better way to do this passing `this` in the function. Here `this` is the image whick will be clicked.

```
<input type="image" src="Images/img.png" onclick="imgChange(this)">
```

```
function imgChange(img){
   img.src = "./Images/img2.png";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly fine

```js
function imgChange() {
  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7166/6621290239_250dce025d_b.jpg";

}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7440/8838399307_9e9e9668f6_b.jpg" id="img" onclick="imgChange()">
```

You can also try moving the images to the same directory as the HTML file to make it simpler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work perfectly in the example below. I would suggest checking that the references to the image sources you are using are valid, as that's the only thing I changed.

```js
  function imgChange() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");

    img.src = "https://www.tompetty.com/sites/g/files/g2000007521/f/styles/photo-carousel/public/Sample-image10-highres.jpg?itok=TDZEPjP8";

  }
```

```html
<input type="image" src="https://www.tompetty.com/sites/g/files/g2000007521/f/styles/photo-carousel/public/sample001.jpg?itok=0Riiujkr" id="img" onclick="imgChange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

should work as is,
but you could try passing the element into the function.

```js
function imgChange(img){
  img.src = "https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/pk/wallhaven-pkgkkp.png"
}
```

```html
<img src="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/rd/wallhaven-rdwjj7.jpg" onclick="imgChange(this)">
```